What statistics to use compare many (dependent) ratios
I'm trying to compare the cellular subpopulations of the thymus of transgenic mice. I identify the cells with flow cytometry, and I get results similar to this:



Cell type
Mouse strain 1
Mouse strain 2




A
10000; 9000; ...
25000;45000;...


B
200;150;...
800;1200;...


C
50;20;...
400;600;...


D
100;50;...
600;800;...



(I have around five replicates for each group)
Because the overall cell count is higher in 'Mouse 2', I also want to see if there is a change in the overall composition, so I calculated percentages by dividing each value by the total cell count.
My main goal is to decide if there is a significant difference between any subpopulation (A, B, C or D) of 'Mouse Strain 1' and 'Mouse Strain 2'
However, this creates strong dependence among A-B-C-D groups because they always add up to 1, so I believe using Two Way ANOVA or multiple T-tests is inadequate.
Could you suggest a different approach or statistical test for this case?

When you say that you have 5 replicates do you mean that you have 5 different samples from 5 different mice (in each cell type and strain) or that you repeated the experiment five times on the same rat (in each cell type and strain)? Overall composition (as in fraction) compared to the 4 different cell types? It looks like strain 2 has more cells in all groups, why? Are there other cells which weren't counted?

-I used 5 mice and measured the cell count for A, B, C and D.
"Overall composition (as in fraction) compared to the 4 different cell types?"
-Yes, e.g. for Mouse Strain 1, replicate 1. The values are: 10000; 200; 50; 100. So the overall cell count is 10350, and the ratios are around 96.6%; 1.9%; 0.5%; 1%, respectively
"It looks like strain 2 has more cells in all groups, why? Are there other cells which weren't counted?"
That's exactly why I want to calculate the ratios. The organ I compare between the two strains differ significantly, hence the visible change in cell counts.
